# Symfony 3.4 login form always return "Invalid credentials"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, authentication, symfony-3.4

I'm struggling to make a Symfony (version 3.4) login form work. 
It always returns "Invalid Credentials" when I try to login. 
A test user (with an encrypted password) is already stored into a MySql database.

I just followed the documentation example that can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/form_login_setup.html).

This is the security.yml file:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        pattern: ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
```

This is the User.php entity:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->isActive = true;
    // may not be needed, see section on salt below
    // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}


public function getSalt()
{
    // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
    // see section on salt below
    return null;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword($password)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

}

This is the controller:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;   
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

}

And finally, the twig template:

```
{# app/Resources/views/security/login.html.twig #}

{% extends 'default.html.twig' %}

{% block pageTitle %} Login {% endblock %}

{% block pageStyle %} {{ parent() }} {% endblock %}

{% block pageScriptsHeader %} {{ parent() }} {% endblock %}

{% block navigation %} {{ parent() }} {% endblock %}

{% block mainContainer %}

{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
    </div>

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">login</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

I suppose that the problem is related to the password. It may be not encrypted before the comparison with the database?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use XDebug to check if the comparaison of the passwords match manually if it does not, copy the encoded password to the database. Then check why the enoding of the registration it is not in sync with the encoding of the login check

Comment: Thank you @albert, I didn't use XDebug but discovered that the problem is related to the registration controller. In fact, the password stored into the db comes from $password and not $plainPassword. The latter field should have been checked for errors and stored into the db by the registration controller.